# Variable guards for strings in overloaded function

Tags: typescript

The guards for strings doesn't work in typescript. When I assign the return type of function to variable out, it will complain that I can't assign a type twice as per function returns. The error is: subsequent variable declaration must have the same type, on the second assignment of "out".

Typescript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=import%20xs%2C%20%7B%20Stream%2C%20MemoryStream%20%7D%20from%20'xstream'%3B%0D%0Aimport%20%7B%20DevToolEnabledSource%20%7D%20from%20'%40cycle%2Frun'%3B%0D%0Aimport%20%7B%20adapt%20%7D%20from%20'%40cycle%2Frun%2Flib%2Fadapt'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20asdf%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20_name%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20events%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20GlobalEventHandlersEventMap%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20eventType%3A%20K%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20options%3F%3A%20EventsFnOptions%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3A%20Stream%3CGlobalEventHandlersEventMap%5BK%5D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20events(eventType%3A%20%22resize%22)%3A%20Stream%3CwindowSize%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20stream%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20let%20out%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20if%20(eventType%20%3D%3D%20%22resize%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(eventType%20%3D%3D%20%22resize%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stream%20%3D%20fromEvent(window%2C%20'resize')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.map(windowSize)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.startWith(windowSize())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.remember()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20out%3A%20DevToolEnabledSource%20%26%20Stream%3CwindowSize%3E%20%3D%20adapt(stream)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20out._isCycleSource%20%3D%20this._name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stream%20%3D%20fromEvent(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20eventType%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20out%3A%20DevToolEnabledSource%20%26%20Stream%3CEvent%3E%20%3D%20adapt(stream)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20out._isCycleSource%20%3D%20this._name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20out%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20windowSize%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20width%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20height%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20windowSize()%3A%20windowSize%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20window.innerWidth%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%20window.innerHeight%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20fromEvent(%0D%0A%20%20element%3A%20Window%2C%0D%0A%20%20eventName%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20useCapture%20%3D%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20passive%20%3D%20false%0D%0A)%3A%20Stream%3CEvent%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20next%3A%20((e%3A%20Event)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7C%20null%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20Stream.create%3CEvent%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20start%3A%20function%20start(listener%3A%20Listener%3CEvent%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(preventDefault)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20next%20%3D%20function%20_next(event%3A%20Event)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20preventDefaultConditional(event%2C%20preventDefault)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20listener.next(event)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20next%20%3D%20function%20_next(event%3A%20Event)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20listener.next(event)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20element.addEventListener(eventName%2C%20next%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20capture%3A%20useCapture%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20passive%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stop%3A%20function%20stop()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20element.removeEventListener(eventName%2C%20next%20as%20any%2C%20useCapture)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20next%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20as%20Producer%3CEvent%3E)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20matchObject(matcher%3A%20object%2C%20obj%3A%20object)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20keys%20%3D%20Object.keys(matcher)%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20n%20%3D%20keys.length%3B%0D%0A%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20n%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20k%20%3D%20keys%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20matcher%5Bk%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object'%20%26%26%20typeof%20obj%5Bk%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!matchObject(matcher%5Bk%5D%2C%20obj%5Bk%5D))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(matcher%5Bk%5D%20!%3D%3D%20obj%5Bk%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20preventDefaultConditional(%0D%0A%20%20event%3A%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20preventDefault%3A%20PreventDefaultOpt%0D%0A)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(preventDefault)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20preventDefault%20%3D%3D%3D%20'boolean')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(isPredicate(preventDefault))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(preventDefault(event))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(typeof%20preventDefault%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(matchObject(preventDefault%2C%20event))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'preventDefault%20has%20to%20be%20either%20a%20boolean%2C%20predicate%20function%20or%20object'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isPredicate(fn%3A%20any)%3A%20fn%20is%20Predicate%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20typeof%20fn%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

```
  public events<K extends keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap>(
    eventType: K,
    // options?: EventsFnOptions,
  ): Stream<GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[K]>
  public events(eventType: "resize"): Stream<windowSize>{
    let stream
    // let out
    // if (eventType == "resize") {
    if (eventType == "resize") {

      stream = fromEvent(window, 'resize')
        .map(windowSize)
        .startWith(windowSize())
        .remember();
      var out: DevToolEnabledSource & Stream<windowSize> = adapt(stream)
      out._isCycleSource = this._name
    } else {
      stream = fromEvent(
        window,
        eventType,
      )
      var out: DevToolEnabledSource & Stream<Event> = adapt(stream)
      out._isCycleSource = this._name
    }
    return out;
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. None of that code assigns to `out`. Does it say the implementation signature is not compatible with the function overload (right now it's using narrower types in the implementation signature, but it should probably be the other way around)? Maybe post the full code and error messages.

Comment: Could you edit this question to provide a [mcve], preferably one which can be demonstrated in a standalone environment like the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//)?  It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: added full example, and typescript playground example.

Comment: ? `let out: DevToolEnabledSource & (Stream<windowSize> | Stream<Event>);` I would say that having different types for `out` based on different `var` declarations is definitely a bad practice. Either return from that point (and don't use `var`) or declare `out` once above the code.

Comment: return out has error has that  basically windowsize | event isn't assignable to windowsize

Comment: @janat08 Yes, you are trying to return one of two different types and your return signature would need to match. The code that uses it would also need to be able to accommodate either return type.

Comment: Signature does match different return types, only that it complains that it shouldnt

Comment: lol using doesn't different variables doesn't help either.

Comment: How does `public events(eventType: "resize"): Stream<windowSize>{` match the return of a variable declared as `DevToolEnabledSource & Stream<Event>`?

Comment: it doesn't, I believe it can have more properties than is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the code to just the relevant parts and stubbing out missing definitions, I've changed the `events` method to return a `Stream<windowSize | Event>` to match one of the two possible return types.

I've also made `out` a `const` variable, which is only local to that scope, and returns it directly from there.

```
class Stream<T> {}

class DevToolEnabledSource {
  public _isCycleSource: string; 
}

interface windowSize {
  width: number,
  height: number,
}

function adapt(x: any): any {}

class example {
  private _name: string;

  public events(eventType: "resize"): Stream<windowSize | Event> {
    let stream;
    if (eventType == "resize") {
      const out: DevToolEnabledSource & Stream<windowSize> = adapt(stream)
      out._isCycleSource = this._name
      return out;
    } else {
      const out: DevToolEnabledSource & Stream<Event> = adapt(stream)
      out._isCycleSource = this._name
      return out;
    }
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=class%20Stream%3CT%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DevToolEnabledSource%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20_isCycleSource%3A%20string%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20windowSize%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20width%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20height%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20adapt(x%3A%20any)%3A%20any%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20_name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20public%20events(eventType%3A%20%22resize%22)%3A%20Stream%3CwindowSize%20%7C%20Event%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20stream%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(eventType%20%3D%3D%20%22resize%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20out%3A%20DevToolEnabledSource%20%26%20Stream%3CwindowSize%3E%20%3D%20adapt(stream)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20out._isCycleSource%20%3D%20this._name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20out%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20out%3A%20DevToolEnabledSource%20%26%20Stream%3CEvent%3E%20%3D%20adapt(stream)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20out._isCycleSource%20%3D%20this._name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20out%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

In answer to the question of only having to declare `out` once: yes, that is possible.

```
let out: Stream<windowSize | Event>;
...
// assign out one way or the other
...
return out;
```

Comment: I suppose that was the only way to do it

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to have a signle return statement if you don't with to repeat yourself?

Comment: Still complains that you can't assign stuff, if you're using EventMap so that people could see the type of event.

Comment: peculiar thing, I couldn't reproduce error in playground with strict settings.

Comment: @janat08 Yes, you can declare `out` once, but you need to declare it as `Stream<windowSize | Event>` when declared, and I do suggest avoiding `var` and instead using `let` at the top. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Also, when *using* the return data from this function, the caller would need to determine if it was a `Stream<windowSize>` or a `Stream<Event>` to know how to cast or narrow the type so that the specific data from `windowSize` or `Event` could be used (but that would be a separate question).